# Ordenar valores Concatenados MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

necesito ordenar unos valores concatenados con GROUP_CONCAT pero el primer valor concatenado no es el que busco ordenar. Este seria el codigo SQL

```
SELECT objects.*, GROUP_CONCAT(mvalues.value SEPARATOR ', ') as value, 
GROUP_CONCAT(mdescriptor.name SEPARATOR ', ') as name  FROM objects JOIN 
metadata_values mvalues ON objects.idObject = mvalues.idObject JOIN 
metadata_descriptors mdescriptor ON mvalues.idDescriptor = 
mdescriptor.idDescriptor WHERE objectType = 'EMBED' AND mdescriptor.name 
IN ('Year Created', 'Thumbnail Patch') GROUP BY objects.idObject ORDER BY 
value ASC
```

Si hay una manera mas sencilla de separar el Thumbnail y Year Created seria mejor.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Dentro de `GROUP_CONCAT` puedes usar `ORDER BY` para ordenar los elementos que se agrupan/concatenan.

Comment: Eso era lo que buscaba. Revise la documentacion de GROUP_CONCAT y logre ordenarlo pero hay manera de Tratar esas agrupacion como columnas diferentes?

Comment: Puedes hacer tantos `GROUP_CONCAT` como quieras.